# iOS - How to remove implicit imports?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, swiftlint

In my team, we develop several frameworks and in one of the apps integrating said frameworks, they want to enforce the imports of FooBar framework to a specific folder and throw a compile time warning if someone tries to import FooBar outside that folder.

I created a swiftlint rule to detect imports of FooBar outside the folder and it turns out that it also detects some implicit imports that should not be there and throws a warning from my lint rule. Even if the file doesn't explictly import FooBar, it seems to have access to it.

Note: FooBar is an static framework that has both ObjC and swift support and the app project also uses both ObjC and swift to access the framework's functionality.

How can I get rid of implicit imports in an iOS project?

Here's the rule I created

```
oneplayer_import:
    exclude: "somepath"
    regex: "^#?import .*FooBar.*$"
    message: "FooBar frameworks should not be imported outside somepath"
    severity: warning
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by "implicit" import?

Comment: Can you show some code examples imports in swift/Objective-C that are authorised /not authorised ?